# Groovy Integration with Java / Spring results in classcastexception

Tags: java, groovy

I am using Spring Boot starter 2.3.1, Groovy-all 2.4.13. I have a mechanism which enables me to execute Groovy Scripts at runtime from within my Java program. Something like below:

```
GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class<Script> pScriptClass = groovyShell.parse(pScriptString).getClass();
Script pScriptObject = pScriptClass.newInstance();
pScriptObject.setBinding(pBinding);
return pScriptObject.invokeMethod("process", null);
```

This is running fine as long as the script does not involve any casting. However, in one of my script, I've a class casting like below:

```
Object process(){
   RestServiceUtil resServ = (RestServiceUtil) applicationContext.getBean("restServiceUtil");
   .
   .
   .
}
```

In the case above I understand that the LHS refers to the class object from the GroovyClassLoader whereas the RHS is from the java class loader. However, from whatever I dug up, this should not create problem since the GroovyShell was created with java class loader as parent i.e. **new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader())**

But when I try to run this script, I still see class cast exception. Since the Groovy class loader is using the Java class loader as parent I was thinking we shouldn't have two separately compiled instances.

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'com.bell.na.nt.bnsm.nets.consumer.utils.RestServiceUtil@1f239d3f' with class 'com.bell.na.nt.bnsm.nets.consumer.utils.RestServiceUtil$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$88984819' to class 'com.bell.na.nt.bnsm.nets.consumer.utils.RestServiceUtil'
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnSAM(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:405) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.continueCastOnNumber(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:319) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:232) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:603) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at Script33.process(Script33.groovy:16) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:803) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:80) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at com.bell.na.nt.remedy.groovy.NetsUtilityGroovyUtils.execute(NetsUtilityGroovyUtils.java:62) ~[ms-nets-utility-library-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at com.bell.na.nt.json.utils.NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.getJsonValue(NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.java:260) [ms-nets-utility-library-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at com.bell.na.nt.json.utils.NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.createPlainJsonObjectFromJsonObject(NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.java:169) [ms-nets-utility-library-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at com.bell.na.nt.json.utils.NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils$createPlainJsonObjectFromJsonObject.call(Unknown Source) [ms-nets-utility-library-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at Script8.process(Script8.groovy:17) [shell:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:803) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:46) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:80) [groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at com.bell.na.nt.remedy.groovy.NetsUtilityGroovyUtils.execute(NetsUtilityGroovyUtils.java:62) [ms-nets-utility-library-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at com.bell.na.nt.json.utils.NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.getJsonValue(NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.java:260) [ms-nets-utility-library-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at com.bell.na.nt.json.utils.NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.createPlainJsonObjectFromJsonObject(NetsUtilityJSONDatumUtils.java:169) [ms-nets-utility-library-1.0.jar:1.0]
    at com.bell.na.nt.bnsm.nets.consumer.service.BNSMNETSReaderService.transformJSONMsg(BNSMNETSReaderService.java:138) [classes/:?]
    at com.bell.na.nt.bnsm.nets.consumer.service.BNSMNETSReaderService.iterativelyTrnsfrmJSON(BNSMNETSReaderService.java:117) [classes/:?]
    at com.bell.na.nt.bnsm.nets.consumer.service.BNSMNETSReaderService.processEventMessage(BNSMNETSReaderService.java:76) [classes/:?]
    at com.bell.na.nt.bnsm.nets.consumer.processor.EventReaderMessageProcessor.processMessage(EventReaderMessageProcessor.java:42) [classes/:?]
    at com.bell.na.nt.kafka.consumer.KafkaConsumer.onMessage(KafkaConsumer.java:52) [spring-kafka-consumer-module-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_282]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171) [spring-messaging-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120) [spring-messaging-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:48) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:329) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:86) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1878) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1860) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1797) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1737) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1634) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1364) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1080) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:988) [spring-kafka-2.5.4.RELEASE.jar:2.5.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_282]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
```

Any help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you have look with `-verbose`, where `RestServiceUtil` is loaded from? Maybe twice?

Comment: Thanks @Turo. I will try this option to check for multiples ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it was two different classloader hierarchy which was causing the problem. Java class loader and then there was this GroovyClassLoader which had separate instance of the same Object that it was trying to cast to i.e. something similar to what we see below.

[image]

Therefore the following way to initialize groovyclassloader using the java class loader as parent should work.
**GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(this.getClass().getClassLoader());**